# The report execution eiisk4vexgtpva3klfmm0hbu has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm running report, however, this report is running since 2 days. When I executed query from backend its gives me result in 10mins. So I checked the log files and changed the timeout value to "Never timeout" from browser and report setting.
I followed this (http://www.avyuktasolutions.com/blog/sql-server-reporting-services-timeout-settings/) to remove report execution timeout and site setting timeout(now both will never timeout). Do I need to remove any other timeout to make this report run quickly, instead of 2days?

With report execution timeout and site setting timeout to never; Again when I'm running the report , its showing me this error:

```
 The report execution eiisk4vexgtpva3klfmm0hbu has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)
```

Please help.

Comment: you can always try to understand why it takes 10min to return your dataset. How many rows are being returned to that report?

Comment: Its around 4500 rows. But, wanted to understand, how does it matter to the problem I have? This is not that much huge data.

Comment: Preload your dataset to a table, so your report won't have to wait 10min and try again.